# Although, but, yet, meanwhile

Tags: word-choice

> ______ understaffed and under tight budget, 911 centers are struggling to adequately provide emergency assistance to the citizens.

There are four choices to fill in the blank:

1. Yet
2. Meanwhile
3. But
4. Although

After considering the meaning of the sentence, I chose "meanwhile" to fill in the blank, but the book which I am using chose "although". Therefore, I am kind of confused here because I think we just use "although" when there are two contradictory sentences or ideas. So, could someone please help me to explain the problem here?

Comment: I see no blank placeholder in the sentence where "yet, meanwhile, but, although" might be placed.  Perhaps I misunderstand?

Comment: The "..." is presumably the placeholder. I don't like ***any*** of the options here.

Comment: This question needs the full context.  *Although* implies some contrary statement earlier.

Comment: This is hopelessly ***Unclear what you're asking*** - without the ***preceding*** text, how can we begin to guess which of OP's four ["conjunctive adverbs"](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/adverbs/list-of-conjunctive-adverbs.html) might be most suitable? From what we *can* see, I find the juxtaposition of ***understaffed***  and ***under** tight budget* a bit clunky (unless it's deliberate, it's not really a good idea to use the word ***under*** with two significantly different senses so close together).

Comment: The problem as I see it is that none of those 4 words work. What would work is something like "Because they are...". If something along those lines was in the list of options there'd be no issue. Or if it said "managing" instead of "struggling". So yes there's a problem with the question, but it's not *necessarily* that there is relevant context missing.

Comment: I think there is no further context. It sounds like what the OP posted is the full question that was on his or her test. Perhaps the OP can confirm if that is the case or clarify if it isn't.

Comment: _Although_ works just fine: _Although understaffed and under tight budget, 911 centers are struggling to adequately provide emergency assistance to the citizens._ (That simply means "Even though they are understaffed..."). This looks like an [ell.se] question to me. I suggest the moderators migrate it there, or the O.P. check out that community.

Comment: This is pretty typical of many questions we get here. There's a test, or a textbook, or a homework assignment, based one `The One Correct Answer`, and of course it's bullshit. So somebody is trying to make sense out of it. Good for them. But Garbage in produces garbage out. Try to explain to the OQ that (a) wherever that question came from, it's not a good place to be, and it's **wrong**, and (b) in order to ask someone a question about a language, there must be **a lot** of context given. Just asking the question like you might ask your rommate doing homework will not generate an answer.

Comment: @J.R. Although grammatical with "although" at the start, the sentence struggles to make sense. Unless, that is, one expects understaffed centres to perform well.

Comment: The problem is that "struggling to adequately provide" can be read either as "adequately providing, but having a difficult time doing so" or "attempting to adequately provide, but failing at it". _Although_ would work for the first interpretation, but not the second.

Comment: @J.R. "Although" implies an internal dissonance, e.g. "Although understaffed ..., 911 call centers adequately provide..."  would be fine, but the "struggling" part of the OP's example makes that half reinforce the first, not contradict it, so "although" sounds very wrong. Assuming the OP isn't omitting an entire first half of a sentence, which says something about how good EMS is.

Comment: @Rupe - I believe the sentence is attempting to say: _Even though 911 centers are understaffed and under tight budget, they are still striving to adequately provide emergency assistance to the citizens._ Also, I believe the point of the exercise is to emphasize how, of these four words – yet, meanwhile, but, although – only the last works as a first word in a sentence that says, _Although X is true, Y still happens._ Between the testmakers using the perhaps poorly-chosen _struggle_ in lieu of _strive_, and the test taker using an ellipsis in place of a blank, the result is a bit of ELU chaos.

Comment: @phenry - Precisely why I believe the first interpretation is the intended one.

Comment: I would've said "meanwhile," as well simply because the other 3 options all indicate some conflict/negation, which doesn't appear in the rest of the sentence. As stated above, you don't "struggle" if you're well-staffed & funded, so the other 3 choices don't make any sense. It all rests on that poor word choice; if it said they're "managing" or "fighting" to provide adequate care then it would indicate positive results, and I'd agree "although" is the best choice.

Comment: @mc01 _Meanwhile_ would make the sentence completely ungrammatical unless you add extra punctuation; it does not work at all.

Answer (score 4):

I think that the poster's supposedly wrong answer would work fine under two conditions: (1) the poster is allowed to add a comma after "Meanwhile"; and (2) the sentence in question, rather than having fallen out of the blue, blue sky, appears in the context of a preceding sentence that says something to set up the contrast that "Meanwhile" attempts to convey.

For example:

> New York City's innovative, privately operated Puppy Ambulance service caters exclusively to AKC-registered blue-blood canines in distress, for pet-loving citizens who can afford the steep fees involved. Meanwhile, understaffed and under tight budget, 911 centers are struggling to adequately provide emergency assistance to the citizens.

It wouldn't be hard to set up similar similar contexts that made the "Yet" and "But" options perfectly reasonable, as well.

I suspect, however, that the test deviser intended to set up a situation where no prior context is allowed, and where the sentence must make sense without reference to anything outside the included wording plus the optional opening word. In that case, as J.R. indicates in a couple of comments beneath the original question, "Although" is the only arguably satisfactory choice.

But the test deviser severely undercuts the sentence's independent readability by referring at the end of it to "the citizens" (rather than simply to "citizens")—as though the reader has already been introduced to these particular individuals. As devised, the sentence invites the test taker to assume that outside context exists for "the citizens" but then punishes the test taker for assuming that outside context also exists for a transitional word such as "Meanwhile" or "But." You can't have it both ways—unless you're the test deviser and you make all the rules yourself.

No wonder the poster was confused by this test question. Bad job, test deviser!

Answer (score 3):

*Although* is the only one of the four which is a subordinating conjunction. Without it, the relationship of the first clause to the following sentence is unclear.

Comment: *Although* doesn't really work, though. If you read the sentence literally with *although,* it says that the centers are struggling ***despite the fact*** that they are understaffed and underfunded. But presumably they're struggling ***because*** they are understaffed and underfunded. This kind of grammatical mistake doesn't belong on an English text.

Comment: I agree that it doesn't make a lot of sense. But it's the only one that works syntactically.